# Excel: reformat/replace part of string in cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an Excel file that contains descriptions:

```
Trees [1]
Buildings[20]
Cameras[303]
```

What I'm wanting to do is format what's inside the brackets to contain 4 digits. I know the custom format is "0000", but can I apply that format to those numbers?

The end result would look like:

```
Trees [0001]
Buildings[0020]
Cameras[0303]
```

Thank you for any tips!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to assume that your number is always in `[]`, and those only occur once per string.

Using `LEFT` and `MID` to slice the string up, and then formatting the number, I end up with a formula that looks like this:

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND("[",A1)) & TEXT(VALUE(MID(A1,FIND("[",A1)+1,FIND("]",A1)-FIND("[",A1)-1)),"0000") & "]"
```

Broken down:

`=LEFT(A1,FIND("[",A1))` << grab all the letters up to the **[**

`&` then add in:

`TEXT(VALUE(MID(A1,FIND("[",A1)+1,FIND("]",A1)-FIND("[",A1)-1)),"0000")` << the number (**VALUE**) found between the brackets (**FIND**), and then format that number (**TEXT**) to be the format you desire

`&` then add in:

`"]"` << the final close bracket

Comment: thank you for the answer and especially for the breakdown! saved the day

Answer (score 3):

Assuming Trees[1] is on A1 cell, then try this formula:

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND("[",A1))&RIGHT("0000"&MID(A1,FIND("[",A1)+1,LEN(A1)-FIND("[",A1)-1),4)&"]"
```